# How to use 0x (for node.js profiling) in combination with TS-Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node, flamegraph

I'm using ts-node to execute scripts written in TypeScript. I would like to inspect a flamegraph using [0x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/0x). Here is the current command I'm executing with ts-node:

`> ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register scripts/my-script.ts`

How would I use 0x to capture a flamegraph of the scripts execution? Or, is there another way to capture a flamegraph of the executed code?

Answer (score 6):

There is an option for passing arguments to node using flamegraph.

Pass custom arguments to node:

```
0x -- node --zero-fill-buffers my-app.js
```

So in your case, you can try:

```
0x -- node -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register scripts/my-script.ts
```